# Clear all values in fields when input field length is less than 7

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I've created a web app where you can search for the employee details using app script.

I have a single input textbox and some disabled fields to display some data.

Actual Web App

[image]

Here's the code

[image]

The input field length is 7 numbers only and what I want is, when I delete 1 number and the length becomes 6 the disabled field will be empty.

Is there a way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Comment: you can try with onchange event: `<select onchange="myFunction()">`

Comment: `document.getElementById("zip").addEventListener("input",clearFields)`

Comment: Mplungjan's answer is better. The listeners should´t never go in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add input listener for #zip input
try this :

```
document.getElementById("zip").addEventListener("input", function(){
   if((this.value).length < 7){
      document.getElementById('est').value = "";
      document.getElementById('Eadd').value = "";
      document.getElementById('role').value = "";
      document.getElementById('rd').value = "";
      document.getElementById('prod').value = "";
      document.getElementById('Aht').value = "";
      document.getElementById('Ave').value = "";
   }
});
```